# Exporting search bookmarks in Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, search, bookmarks, chromium

Is it possible to export my Chromium search bookmarks to Opensearch format?

Comment: What is a 'search bookmark'?

Comment: Perhaps not the correctest of words. On firefox any keyword search is stored as a bookmark, and I guess that is when I developed this part of my lexicon. My list of search engines.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't export them.

However, you can pass them from one Chrome profile to another. The file is located in `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data`. Just copy it from the older profile to the new one.

The file is actually a SQLite Database, so technically you could write a script that reads the file and exports it.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I'm looking for, but what is the path on Linux?

Comment: ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/ I think, but I can't verify.